# Ng-options not working, not matter what i try

Tags: html, angular, typescript

This is my select

```
<select ng-options="country.country for country in countries" formControlName="country"></select></label>
```

and this is the component typescript:

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth/auth.service'
import { Router, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { FirestoreService } from '../../services/firestore/firestore.service';
import { User } from '../../models/user/user.model';

import countriesJSON from '../../json/countries-and-states.json';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-register',
  templateUrl: './login-register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login-register.component.css']
})
export class LoginRegisterComponent {

  registerForm: FormGroup;
  errorMessage: string = '';
  successMessage: string = '';
  users: User[];
  countries = countriesJSON.countries;

  constructor(
    public authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private fireservice: FirestoreService
  ) {
    this.createForm();

   }

   createForm() {
     this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
       email: ['', Validators.required ],
       password: ['',Validators.required],
       repassword: ['',Validators.required],
       age: ['',Validators.required],
       state: ['',Validators.required],
       country: ['',Validators.required]
     });
   }

   tryGoogleLogin(){
     this.authService.doGoogleLogin()
     .then(res =>{
       this.router.navigate(['/user']);
     }, err => console.log(err)
     )
   }

   tryRegister(value){
     this.authService.doRegister(value)
     .then(res => {
       console.log(res);
       this.fireservice.createUser(value);
       this.errorMessage = "";
       this.successMessage = "Your account has been created";
     }, err => {
       console.log(err);
       this.errorMessage = err.message;
       this.successMessage = "";
     })
   }

   register(user: User){

  }

  update(user: User) {
    this.fireservice.updateUser(user);
  }
  ngOnInit(){
    console.log(this.countries);

  }
}
```

And the json:

```
    {
  "countries": [
    {
      "country": "Afghanistan",
      "states": ["Badakhshan", "Badghis", "Baghlan", "Balkh", "Bamian", "Daykondi", "Farah", "Faryab", "Ghazni", "Ghowr", "Helmand", "Herat", "Jowzjan", "Kabul", "Kandahar", "Kapisa", "Khost", "Konar", "Kondoz", "Laghman", "Lowgar", "Nangarhar", "Nimruz", "Nurestan", "Oruzgan", "Paktia", "Paktika", "Panjshir", "Parvan", "Samangan", "Sar-e Pol", "Takhar", "Vardak", "Zabol"]
    },
    {
      "country": "Albania",
      "states": ["Berat", "Dibres", "Durres", "Elbasan", "Fier", "Gjirokastre", "Korce", "Kukes", "Lezhe", "Shkoder", "Tirane", "Vlore"]
    },
    {
      "country": "Algeria",
      "states": ["Adrar", "Ain Defla", "Ain Temouchent", "Alger", "Annaba", "Batna", "Bechar", "Bejaia", "Biskra", "Blida", "Bordj Bou Arreridj", "Bouira", "Boumerdes", "Chlef", "Constantine", "Djelfa", "El Bayadh", "El Oued", "El Tarf", "Ghardaia", "Guelma", "Illizi", "Jijel", "Khenchela", "Laghouat", "Muaskar", "Medea", "Mila", "Mostaganem", "M'Sila", "Naama", "Oran", "Ouargla", "Oum el Bouaghi", "Relizane", "Saida", "Setif", "Sidi Bel Abbes", "Skikda", "Souk Ahras", "Tamanghasset", "Tebessa", "Tiaret", "Tindouf", "Tipaza", "Tissemsilt", "Tizi Ouzou", "Tlemcen"]
    },
    {
      "country": "Andorra",
      "states": ["Andorra la Vella", "Canillo", "Encamp", "Escaldes-Engordany", "La Massana", "Ordino", "Sant Julia de Loria"]
    },
    {
      "country": "Angola",
      "states": ["Bengo", "Benguela", "Bie", "Cabinda", "Cuando Cubango", "Cuanza Norte", "Cuanza Sul", "Cunene", "Huambo", "Huila", "Luanda", "Lunda Norte", "Lunda Sul", "Malanje", "Moxico", "Namibe", "Uige", "Zaire"]
    },
    {
      "country": "Antarctica",
      "states": []
    },
    {
      "country": "Antigua and Barbuda",
      "states": ["Barbuda", "Redonda", "Saint George", "Saint John", "Saint Mary", "Saint Paul", "Saint Peter", "Saint Philip"]
    },
    {
      "country": "Argentina",
      "states": ["Buenos Aires", "Buenos Aires Capital", "Catamarca", "Chaco", "Chubut", "Cordoba", "Corrientes", "Entre Rios", "Formosa", "Jujuy", "La Pampa", "La Rioja", "Mendoza", "Misiones", "Neuquen", "Rio Negro", "Salta", "San Juan", "San Luis", "Santa Cruz", "Santa Fe", "Santiago del Estero", "Tierra del Fuego", "Tucuman"]
    },
```

... and there is more, but its the same.

I've tried puting {{countries[2].country}} in the html and it works perfectly, it shows a country.
And tried the ng-option value in 90 different ways, i don't know what to do.

I've wasted too much time on this, and for sure it's a little thing easy to solve, but i need to know it, cuz i don't haha

Comment: can you post stackblitz link?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-quxc9x

Comment: i have no time to add the whole app, its a big proyect, just added the necessary to know my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you used `ng-options` as in `angularJS`, here in `Angular` it's a bit different

here we can use `option` with `ng-for`

```
  <select formControlName="country"> 
    <option *ngFor="let item of countries" [value]="item.country">{{ item.country }}</option>
  </select>
```

hope it helps